# R Snowfall Environments issues

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snowfall

I am trying to get my head around the Snowfall library and its usage.

Having writing a simulation that makes use of environments, I encountered the following issue. If I source a file to load functions within the parallel mode, the function seems to use a different environment than when I declare the function within parallel mode direclty.

To make things a little bit more clear, lets consider the following two scripts:

**q_func.R** declares the function

```
foo.bar <- function(x, envname) assign("val", x, envir = get(envname))
# assigns the value x to the variable "val" in the environment envname
```

**q_snowfall.R** main function that uses snowfall

```
library(snowfall)
SnowFunc <- function(envname) {
    # load the functions

    # Option 1 not working
    source("q_func.R")
    # Option 2 working...
    # foo.bar <- function(x, envname) assign("val", x, envir = get(envname))


    # create the new environment
    assign(envname, new.env())

    # use the function as declared in q_func.R 
    # to assign random numbers to the new env
    foo.bar(x = rnorm(1), envname = envname)

    # return the environment including the random values
    return(get("val", envir = get(envname)))
}

sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 2)
# create environment 'a' and 'b' that each will get a new variable 
# called 'val' that gets assigned a random value

envs <- c("a", "b")
result <- sfClusterApplyLB(envs, SnowFunc)
sfStop()
```

If I execute the script "q_snowfall.R" I get the error

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'a' not found
```

However, if I use the second option (declaring the function within the SnowFunc-function the error disappears.

Do you know how Snowfall handles the different environments? Or do you even have a solution for the issue. (note that 'q_func.R' actually takes some 100 lines of code, therefore I would prefer to have it in a separate file, thus the "keep option 2" is not a solution!)

Thank you very much!

**Edit** 
If I change all `get(envname)` to `get(envname, envir = globalenv())` it seems to work. But it seems to me that this is more or less a workaround and not a very snowfall-like solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is not with `snowfall` but with the fact that you're passing the environment by name (as character). You don't need to change all occurences of `get`, and having it look in `globalEnv` may indeed be unsafe.

It is sufficient to change the `get` call in `foo.bar` to look in `parent.frame()` instead (i.e., the environment from which `foo.bar` was called). The following worked on my machine.

new **q_func.R**

```
foo.bar <- function(x, envname) assign("val", x, envir=get(envname,
                                pos=parent.frame()))
```

(not so) new **q_snowfall.R**

```
library(snowfall)
SnowFunc <- function(envname) {

    assign(envname, new.env())
    foo.bar(x = rnorm(1), envname = envname)

    return(get("val", envir = get(envname)))
}

source("q_func.R")
sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 2)
sfExport("foo.bar")

envs <- c("a", "b")
result <- sfClusterApplyLB(envs, SnowFunc)
sfStop()
```

Note also that I `source`'d before starting the cluster and used `sfExport` to export `foo.bar` to each node.

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I was looking for!
Additionally, if I need to load (via the get-function) or write (assign) a variable within a function that is declared in another script but called withing another function (... I know.. :) ), I sometimes got the error that the environment wasn't found. My solution was to play around with the parent.frame() function, ie. including n = 2, 3, 4 depending on the nested functions!

Comment: Wht's the difference between snowfall and doSnow?